# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to built a simple calculator and I got an exception.
Does Someone has any clue?

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!   
    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
    @IBAction func touchDigit(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping
        {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
        }
        else
        {
            display.text = digit
        }
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true 
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your ViewController Scene on the left -> right click on "View Controller" -> Check if all your Outlets are links each others (if one have a Warning symbol, just delete it) -> Rebuild your projects